# Is my model overfitting ? Training Acc :93 % test accuracy 82%

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, lightgbm

I am using LGBM model for binary classification. After hyper-parameter tuning I get

```
Training accuracy 0.9340
Test accuracy 0.8213
```

can I say my model is overfitting? Or is it acceptable in the industry?

Also to add to this when I increase the `num_leaves` for the same model,I am able to achieve:

```
Train Accuracy : 0.8675
test accuracy : 0.8137
```

Which one of these results are acceptable and can be reported?

Comment: Why exactly you think you would choose the second set of results, where *both* training and test accuracy are *worse*?

Comment: @desertnaut I'm not currently choosing any. I am confused as to which one is more appropriate to report.

Comment: What does "appropriate" even mean here? A question of "which" implies a choice; so let me rephrase: why you think a model where *both* measures are *worse* might be more appropriate to report?

Comment: @desertnaut I get your point! So if I'm reporting train and test accuracy of the former case i.e. Training accuracy 0.9340
Test accuracy 0.8213, is the model said to be overfitting?

Answer (score 2):

How can we ask this question? Results doesn't simply depends on 'what is the accuracy on training and test sets', there are others side to consider.

What about your data? Is it balanced or not? What type of problem is? Binary or multi class classification?

If you have a binary classification problem where classes are imbalanced, with 95% of samples for the most representative class, and 5% of the other class, then this accuracy is bad, since a dumb classifier which simply always predicts the most representative class should have a 0.95 accuracy, so in that case accuracy isn't the right metric to evaluate your model.

If your problem has 10 balanced classes, then a 0.8+ accuracy is a nice result (compared to the random choice).

Also, to evaluate if your model is or not overfitting, the best thing to do isn't watching accuracy (or recall, precision etc), but the validation loss, since that is what you really want to minimize during the training. If you see that your training loss still decrease while your validation loss starts to increase, then your model is overfitting, since he's not learning, he's just memorizing the training set.

Comment: As I mentioned about at karteek's comment; I have a binary classification problem with 10,629 rows and 12,413 columns. I have mix data i.e. some boolean columns and some numeric feature columns. The data has around 5900 data points with class 0 and 4600 data points with class 1. After feature selection which filters around 6000 features which gives me the above mentioned accuracy score. And I also agree with alone accuracy can't be the measure of over fitting. Also just to be clear I'm a beginner in this field so some of my questions might sound unreasonable. Thanks

Comment: I suggest to reduce the number of features, since 10k samples with 6k features tipically isn't a good rate, check for the [Curse of dimens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Machine_Learning), I think 1500 features is a good trade-off. To reduce it, since you have a lot of features, just remove ones which contains an high number of null values compared to others instead of filling them. Add `'metric': {'l2', 'binary', others metrics like accuracy}` and `'is_training_metric': True`  as training parameters for the model. It should print loss value for each training epoch ...

Comment: ... so you can see how loss change, and check for overfitting. You can also use `early_stopping_rounds=k` to avoid overfitting (it will stop the training if the objective metric doesn't decrease in one epoch compared to the previous epoch for k times). Set `'objective': 'binary'` as training parameter for example. I don't use gradient boosting since a lot, so see [LGBM print loss in each epoch](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1296) for clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Just asking whether you have controlled the parameters with a proper range.
Controlling the parameters like **Gamma, max depth, min child weight, subsample, objective, learning rate, n estimators**. These parameters in particular should be given a range only after what each of the parameters would do and how they impact.

Comment: I have tried to control few of these hyper-parameters by giving the following ranges as per my understanding. I have data with 10,629 rows and 12,413 columns. I have mix data i.e. some boolean columns and some numeric feature columns. I have also tried to apply feature selection which filters around 6000 features which gives me the above mentioned ac curacies which I wanted to know abut as to what to report. please let me know your take. ranges of parameters given : max_depth: (3, 10) ; subsample: (0.01, 1.0); objective: 'binary', metric: 'auc', learning_rate': (0.001, 1); n_estimators= 1000

Comment: Key takeaways.
Due to the dimensionality, you might be feeding more data for which the overfitting is taking place. 12413 columns needs to be reduced drastically.

Comment: yes @Karteek, I also think so that is why I applied chi sqaure and MI based feature selection techniques and now the feature set is somewhere around 6400 only. The accuracy reported above are on that data itself. Also do you have any input on hyperprameter ranges, then it is most welcomed. Thanks

Comment: ranges of parameters given : max_depth: (3, 10)--this is cool ; `subsample: (0.5, 0.7, 1.0)`; objective: 'binary', metric: 'auc', `learning_rate': (0.001, 0.003, 0.006, 0.03)`; n_estimators= `(200, 250, 300, 450, 600, 750)`.

Comment: @As13, you have various other tricks which comes to rescue while dealing with features selection. Here are some. `Constant Removal`, `Quasi Constant Removal`, Duplicate Features removal`, `Mutual information gain`, ROC-AUC` statistical ranking, `Univariate ANOVA`, `Fischer Score`, `Step forward Selection`, `Step backward Selection`, `Exhaustive Feature Selection`, `LRS`, `Regularization(lasso, ridge, elastic net)`, `Tree based Feature Importances`, `Recursive Feature elimination`, `Recursive feature addition`, `Permutation importance`, `Boruta`, `Dimensional reduction using PCA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a cross validation and observe the values you get for the accuracy in the different folds. If they differ a lot, your model is overfitting. If they are close enough, your model is fine.